# FFMPEG Split Mp3 using CSV in Shell, parsing doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, shell, shell-script, csv

**Task**: Split one mp3-files to several mp3-files, use a CSV-File with Starttime, Endtime, and Title.

**Errors**: Skipped Parts, some parts with wrong naming, randomly accruing errors:

- Invalid duration specification for ss: :05
- Invalid duration specification for t: Name4

**Done so far**: Triple-Checked the CSV FIle, changed the Script-Code.

**Files**:

- data.csv

```
   00:01:14,00:08:42,Name1
   00:08:42,00:17:17,Name2
  [...]
```

- Script.sh

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    inputCSV="data.csv"
    inputMP3="audioFile.mp3" 
    i=0
    #ffmpeg -i $inputMP3 -f null -
    while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3
      do
      ((i++))
      #echo "$i $f1 $f2 $f3"
      ffmpeg -i "$inputMP3"  -vn -acodec copy  -ss "$f1"  -t "$f2"   "$i|25 - $f3.mp3"
    done < "$inputCSV"
```

**by the way**: when only using echo "$i $f1 $f2 $f3" instead of the ffmpeg command, the output of the CSV-File is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in [BashFAQ/089](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089). The problem is `ffmpeg` consumes (parts of) stdin, so not all of `data.csv` goes to `read`.

The easiest way to solve this is to make `ffmpeg` read from `/dev/null`:

```
</dev/null ffmpeg …
```

This approach requires a shell, so it's OK in your case. If you ever need something similar without a shell, use the `-nostdin` option (which should work in a shell as well):

```
ffmpeg -nostdin …
```

---

When only using `echo`, there is no `ffmpeg` and `echo` doesn't read from its stdin. In this case only `read` reads from `data.csv`, so the whole loop behaves as you expect.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!